# Why Does Azure Logic App Firing Twice For no Reason

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a Data Factory pipeline that perfroms some pretty simple tasks. For somereason, the Logic App portion of the pipeline is "firing" multiple times, even thouh I'm calling it just once.

So, the pipeline runs three stored procedures. It then exports the results to a Data Lake container. Then lastly, it send an email with the three reports as attachmentsin an email.

I have everything working fine, but there is one odd bit of behavior I'm seeing. The logic app is essentially firing three times when it's called, so I end up getting three emails. It looks like I'm doing everything right.

[Logic App Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZUO7.png)

Logic App

I seems as though it's firing for each attachment / blob content action. I'm fresh out of ideas. If anyone has any thoughts, that would be awesome.

Thank you!

Comment: Your trigger is when a blob is added or modified, is that happening 3 times?  You could change the logic app trigger to http and have the data factory pipeline call the logic app to trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger will be fired if you add/modify the files in the folder which you specified every x minutes(you set it 3 minutes). And if you added/modified three files, the trigger will be fired three times, so you received three emails. You can take a look the runs history of your logic app, every time running the "**Body**" of the trigger will return one file content of the three files.

If you don't want the flow run three three times, you can set the trigger by following steps below:

1. Change the "**Number of blobs to return from the trigger**" to 10 (or any number which you want, but should be greater 3 as you have three files).
   [image]
2. Click the `...` button at the upper right-hand corner of the trigger and click "**Settings**", disable "Split On".
   [image]

After completing the two steps of setting, the "Body" of trigger will return all of the three files in one time, you will receive only one email.

**Update:**

Sorry for missing one step, apart from the steps above we also need to add a "If" condition in the logic app.

Create a "If" condition after the "When a blob is added or modified (properties only)" trigger, the details of the condition shown as below:
[image]

If true, do the steps what you want(such as get the blob content and send emails). If false, do nothing. Then you will just receive one email.

By the way, if you notice the run history, you can see the logic app was triggered two times. In first time, the trigger response the "body" with a `[]` array and in second time the trigger response the "body" with three blob array. This is why we need to add the "If" condition.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I had actually already disabled "Split" and was still getting those multiple emails. As you instructed, I setthe number of blobs to return to 10, and while it didn't solve my problem completely, I'm now only getting two emails with the three attachments versus three emails with all three attachemtns. Is there somethin else I'm overlooking?